# ionic apk file not getting location but the system show location

Tags: android, angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework

When I am running ionic apk file in mobile I'm not getting my location but the system show location. What is the problem?

```
Module.js file 
angular.module('ionic.example', ['ionic'])

    .controller('MapCtrl', function($scope, $ionicLoading, $compile) {
      function initialize() {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(43.07493,-89.381388);

        var mapOptions = {
          center: myLatlng,
          zoom: 16,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
            mapOptions);

        //Marker + infowindow + angularjs compiled ng-click
        var contentString = "<div><a ng-click='clickTest()'>Click me!/a></div>";
        var compiled = $compile(contentString)($scope);

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: compiled[0]
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatlng,
          map: map,
          title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });

        $scope.map = map;
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

      $scope.centerOnMe = function() {
        if(!$scope.map) {
          return;
        }

        $scope.loading = $ionicLoading.show({
          content: 'Getting current location...',
          showBackdrop: false
        });

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
          $scope.map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));
          $scope.loading.hide();
        }, function(error) {
          alert('Unable to get location: ' + error.message);
        });
      };

      $scope.clickTest = function() {
        alert('Example of infowindow with ng-click')
      };

    });
```

Here it is not working after installing apk file. On clicking the find me button it is loading ..... but not showing location

This is my code. When I run the browser it is working fine but after build apk file it is not showing details. Can you guys tell me the what the reason is?

Answer (score 0):

The permissions are set correctly in your androidManifest? you need:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

Try to connect the device to pc and use chrome://inspect to see the error.

Comment: when i am add this lines i got this error ionic.bundle.js:12010 SVG's SMIL animations (<animate>, <set>, etc.) are deprecated and will be removed. Please use CSS animations or Web animations instead.
ionic.bundle.js:21162 $ionicLoading instance.hide() has been deprecated. Use $ionicLoading.hide().